# How to use the /clear command correctly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I used The following:

```
/clear @p (id of item ex:1) 8
```

I wanted to remove only a certain amount of items. Any ideas on how to remove only a few items rather than all of them?

Note: I am using 1.7.10 because I'm using a modpack.

Answer (score 1):

So the syntax of the command is:

```
clear [player] [item] [data] [max-count] [dataTag]
```

So if you wanted to clear your own inventory you would say:

```
/clear
```

If you wanted to clear `rappatic`'s inventory:

```
/clear rappatic
```

If you wanted to clear `rappatic`'s inventory of stone blocks:

```
/clear rappatic minecraft:stone
```

If you wanted to clear `rappatic`'s inventory of blue wool ([here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values#Wool.2C_terracotta.2C_stained_Glass_and_carpet) for data values)

```
/clear rappatic minecraft:wool 11
```

or for all types of wool:

```
/clear rappatic minecraft:wool -1
```

To clear `rappatic`'s inventory of 12 stone blocks:

```
/clear rappatic minecraft:stone 1 12
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#clear):

```
clear [player] [item] [data] [maxCount] [dataTag]
```

For example: `clear @p 1 -1 64`  will remove all kinds of stone up to a stack (-1 in data means match only itemID, so stone, granite, diorite, etc will be removed).

Comment: `/clear` did not support a maximum amount (or even a data value) in 1.7.10.